# I would like to simulate a die from Anima: Beyond Fantasy in the Rolisteam dice roller on Discord. Can I do that, and if so, how?

Tags: tools, dice, anima-beyond-fantasy, rolisteam

As I'm sure anyone who has played it knows, Anima has interesting dice behaviors.

Manually keeping track of them is kind of a pain in the neck, so I was wondering if there was a way to implement them as a single action in [this dice parser, over Discord](https://github.com/Rolisteam).  (my campaign currently uses this dice parser, although if this dice parser *cannot* be used, and a *different* dice parser or dice app (e.g. rolz.org) *can*, that would be something that could be set up.)

The behaviors that are *necessary* for this answer:

1. The die, a d100, explodes on a 90+, which then explodes on a 91+, which then explodes on a 92+, etc., until 100, when it will keep exploding on 100s.
2. The die *fumbles* on the other end of the range, using a passed-in argument, since the fumble range in Anima can vary, in ordinary circumstances, between 2 and 5.  (In extraordinary circumstances, it can vary between 1 and 5.)  The particular stylings of output on a fumble is up to you, but it should handle, at the minimum, a fumble on attack/defense (subtract 1d100 from your roll, which does *not* explode), and a fumble on skills (compare a d100 result to a table).  I am not going to require the core rulebook's +-15 thing, as that has several issues in terms of how exactly it's supposed to work.
3. Preferably, adding arbitrary modifiers to the result should be easy to do.

Additional bonus points (worth no particular value) will be awarded for implementing the luck-manipulation powers in Prometheum Exxet as options, which are as follows and can be combined:

Option A: Die explodes on any doubles roll (11, 22, 33, ...99)

Option B: Die explodes starting at 85, instead of 90.

Comment: The system is pretty similar to role master and LOTR, I suggest you take a look for solutions on those systems.

Comment: @Random If you can point at a solution for that, that would be a good starting point for an answer.

Comment: @Zachiel to be clear, a 100 always explodes.

Comment: This is more of a programming problem to be honest. Something i'd suggest writing in python. Though I know roll20 macro's are capable of doing this with conditions.

Comment: @Riddley That really doesn't answer my question.  Nor does it actually *help*, since I don't have the time to make a dicebot nor the money to host one.

Comment: @Stackstuck didn't find anything myself (I used to play a lot of old school LOTR and even when it was more widely played there were not many tools), sorry for that. But, have you tried contacting the people at Dice Parser? they may have an expression for exploding dice in Anima style, and they definitely know the software better than any of us here. I understand that the question asks for complex stuff, because Anima system is quite complex, but that in itself means that there will not be much out there. 
I also feel that this question will be better suited on their github project.

Comment: @Random I tried on their Discord.  No help is forthcoming from that corner, especially since it's just the one person on the project as far as I understand it.

Comment: Had a look at the documentation here: https://github.com/obiwankennedy/DiceParser/blob/master/HelpMe.md
It looks like its possible to do this... Would require a different formula for the conditional stuff though, unless there's a way to expose variables from the character sheet (It looks like there might be). That said... This would involving fiddling around for a while... Ill post it as an answer when I get around to looking at it with more detail.

Comment: It looks like I'm going to have to figure out how to do this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the HelpMe for rolisteam: [RoliSteam DiceParser](https://github.com/Rolisteam/DiceParser/blob/master/HelpMe.md)

Explode when over 90: `!1d100e[>90]`

Explode when over 85: `!1d100e[>85]`

Having the threshold increase for each success does not seem possible because the system doesn't seem to handle variables, if it did it would look like `!1d100[>Variable]{Variable++}`.

The fumble one is really hard but you should look into the "if-section" of the HelpMe: [DiceParser If](https://github.com/Rolisteam/DiceParser/blob/master/HelpMe.md#if)

Minus 1d100 if fumble(Between 1 and 5): `1d100i.[1-5]{-1d100}`

Comment: Can you explain how you use that to explode on the sequentially-increasing-values-each time that behavior 1 in the question lists? It sounds like the need is more complicated than just exploding on >90.

Comment: From what I can see it is not possible since the system cannot handle variables

Comment: Rolisteam does have macros that can use regular expressions.